# SQL Server - converting 31's to 30's on MonthEnd

Tags: sql-server

I have a little problem with my code, I just want to convert all 31's end of the month to 30's.  I know its a there's a little trick behind it.

```
DECLARE @StartYear DATE = '20170101'
DECLARE @EndYear DATE = '20171231'

;WITH n AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, Dates AS (
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartYear, @EndYear)+1)
      DatesOnSelect = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1,@StartYear))
  FROM n AS deka CROSS JOIN n AS hecto CROSS JOIN n AS kilo 
                CROSS JOIN n AS tenK CROSS JOIN n AS hundredK
   ORDER BY DatesOnSelect
)

SELECT DISTINCT MonthEnd = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,DatesOnSelect )+1, 0)), 101) FROM dates
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Are you trying to use an accounting calendar? It's probably easier to solve the actual problem than try to modify this code

Comment: Why? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: For example, why not create an actual [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) that contains both actual and accounting dates? This would even allow you to use multiple accounting calendars

Comment: T-SQL has an [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) function. You could use it to simplify your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `case` expression to subtract an extra day if the month end is 31.

```
DECLARE @StartYear DATE = '20170101'
DECLARE @EndYear DATE = '20171231'

;WITH n AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, Dates AS (
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartYear, @EndYear)+1)
      DatesOnSelect = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1,@StartYear))
  FROM n AS deka CROSS JOIN n AS hecto CROSS JOIN n AS kilo 
                CROSS JOIN n AS tenK CROSS JOIN n AS hundredK
   ORDER BY DatesOnSelect
)

SELECT DISTINCT MonthEnd 
  = CONVERT(varchar(10),
    case when day(DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,DatesOnSelect )+1, 0)))=31
         then DATEADD(DAY,-2,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,DatesOnSelect )+1, 0))
         else DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,DatesOnSelect )+1, 0))
         end , 101)
FROM dates
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NEXST15257

returns:

```
+------------+
|  MonthEnd  |
+------------+
| 01/30/2017 |
| 02/28/2017 |
| 03/30/2017 |
| 04/30/2017 |
| 05/30/2017 |
| 06/30/2017 |
| 07/30/2017 |
| 08/30/2017 |
| 09/30/2017 |
| 10/30/2017 |
| 11/30/2017 |
| 12/30/2017 |
+------------+
```

Comment: How does this differ from the original code? Code-only answers that don't explain why the code works aren't very helpful

Answer (score 0):

A calendar/tally table would do the trick, but you can all accomplish this with an ad-hoc tally table.  If you need more than 6 years just change the sub-query to `From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2`

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2017-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2017-12-31'


Select D=max(D)
 From (Select Top (DateDiff(DD,@Date1,@Date2)+1) D=DateAdd(DD,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) From  master..spt_values) A
 Where Day(D) between 28 and 30
 Group By Year(D),Month(D)
```

Returns

```
D
2017-01-30
2017-02-28
2017-03-30
2017-04-30
2017-05-30
2017-06-30
2017-07-30
2017-08-30
2017-09-30
2017-10-30
2017-11-30
2017-12-30
```